# java.lang.IllegalStateException:Action Bar Tab must have a Callback

Tags: android

I m developing an app in which i want to use android action bar tab. I used the action bar tab. but it give me an exception when i m running the app. It give exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback". Please help me and thanks in advance

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab().setText("xyzabc");
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
        tab.setTabListener(new TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("pqrabc");
        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: show the logcat plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first set the tab listener and then add it to actionbar:

```
    Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("pqrabc");
    tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener() {...})
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);
```

Comment: Can we change the color of action bar tabs. its showing me black

Comment: @UmeshKumarSaraswat yeah read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs)